# How to Include accented words in regex

Tags: python, regex, capitalization

I have a utf-8 text with capitalized words within the text:

```
La cinta, que hoy se estrena en nuestro país, competirá contra Hors la
Loi, de Argelia, Dogtooth, de Grecia, Incendies, de Canadá, Life above
all , de Sudáfrica, y con la ganadora del Globo de Oro, In A Better
World, de Dinamarca.
```

The desired output is to replace all words that starts with a capital letter to a placeholder (i.e. `#NE#`), except for the first word. So the desired output look as such:

```
La cinta, que hoy se estrena en nuestro país, competirá contra  #NE#
la  #NE# , de #NE# ,  #NE# , de  #NE# ,  #NE# , de  #NE#,  #NE# above
all , de #NE# , y con la ganadora del  #NE# de  #NE# ,  #NE# A #NE# #NE# , de  #NE# .
```

I've tried using regex as follows:

```
>>> import re
>>> def blind_CAPS_without_first_word(text):
...     first_word, _, the_rest = text.partition(' ')
...     blinded = re.sub('(?:[A-Z][\w]+\s*)', ' #NE# ', the_rest)
...     return " ".join([first_word, blinded])
... 
>>> text = "La cinta, que hoy se estrena en nuestro país, competirá contra Hors la Loi, de Argelia, Dogtooth, de Grecia, Incendies, de Canadá, Life above all , de Sudáfrica, y con la ganadora del Globo de Oro, In A Better World, de Dinamarca."
>>> blind_CAPS_without_first_word(text)
```

[out]:

> La cinta, que hoy se estrena en nuestro país, competirá contra  #NE#
>   la  #NE# , de  #NE# ,  #NE# , de  #NE# ,  #NE# , de  #NE# á,  #NE#
>   above all , de  #NE# áfrica, y con la ganadora del  #NE# de #NE# , #NE# A  #NE#  #NE# , de  #NE# .

But the regex didn't consider accented characters when using `\w`, e.g. `Canadá` -> `#NE# á`; `Sudáfrica` -> `#NE# áfrica`. **How do I get around this? How to include accented words in my regex?** It needs to be `Canadá` -> `#NE#`; `Sudáfrica` -> `#NE#`.

I guess it's okay if to ignore single character words like `A` remains as `A`. Unless there's a get around for this.

Comment: I don't know why it fails to replace `La` ?

Comment: because it needs to skip the first word, hence the `str.partition()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `\w+`  or `[\w]+` won't match accented characters. So it fails to match those words.

You may use `\S+` instead of `\w+`

```
re.sub(r'[A-Z]\S+\s*', ' #NE# ', the_rest)
```

**OR**

Use regex module if you only wants to match word chars of any language.

```
regex.sub(r'[A-Z]\p{L}+\s*', ' #NE# ', the_rest)
```

Comment: I know `\w` doesn't match accented characters. What is the get around?

Comment: ahhh non-white space character.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could use unicode notation to capture ranges of characters? Example: [\xC0-\xE1] or something? I ran it by [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) and it didn't seem to mind... you'll need to find your own range, but it's a start :)

Hope this helps.